# String manipulation in C, syntactically correct , but it does not work with MacOS or freeBSD

Tags: c, linux, macos, gcc, bsd

OK  for Linux 32/64  Windows 32/64 compiled with GCC, DOS and OS2 with MS compiler
on Mac OS o BSD compiled with GCC, go to infinity loop

```
char *b,p[]={'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','\0'};
for (b=p;(*(b++)=*b););
printf("p=%s\n",p);

// result:
// 123456789

// Test for MacOS or BSD
unsigned char Test=0x0F;
for (b=p;((*(b++)=*b) && --Test););
if (!Test) printf("Error\n");


// OK for Mac OS or FreeBSD
for (b=p;(*b);b++) *b=*(b+1);
printf("p=%s\n",p);

// result:
// 123456789
```

ok, now it works, but the question remains, why it does not work if the syntax is correct?

Comment: syntax != logic. And please clarify what the program is supposed to do, what the expected output is and what the actual output is. "it works" and "it does not work" isn't exactly descriptive.

Comment: is part of a string processing routines, the routines works perfectly, properly tested on different operating systems, 32bit ubuntu, mint 64, Windows XP, Seven 64-bit as well as for pure whim of DOS and OS2.
as evidenced on BDS like never ending loop, checked by inserting a counter to force the exit.

Comment: For C code in particular, there can be a **BIG** gap between "syntactically correct" and "it works". Something like `printf("2 + 2 = 5");` is perfectly good syntax.

Comment: ok, we see the expressive form.
the routine properly plays the role assigned in the mentioned operating systems, while Mac enters into infinite loop.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that this expression is *unsequenced*:

```
*(b++)=*b
```

Essentially, the value being modified is accessed more than once without a sequence point in between. This means that the behavior is undefined.

Your other expression is free of undefined behavior, because modification happens in the loop header:

```
*b=*(b+1)
```

Comment: exactly, in fact I entered the correction, but I would like to understand why.

Comment: @Blindonet The reason the standard requires a sequence point there is that it wants to give compiler makers a choice as to when exactly the side effect of `++` is to be applied. It can be applied before the assignment or after the assignment, which will either make your program work the way you expect or to break.